# AWS SDK : s3.upload is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload files to my S3 bucket from my Node.js app, so I am following some very simple tutorials like [this one](https://stackabuse.com/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-with-node-js/).

The code is pretty straightforward :

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk"); // fresh install, version : ^2.697.0

AWS.config.update({ // Credentials are OK
    accessKeyId: process.env.s3_accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.s3_secretAccessKey,
    region: 'eu-central-1'
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

let params = {
      // (some upload params, file name, bucket name etc)
 };

s3.upload(params); // <-- crash with error: "s3.upload is not a function"
```

I had a look at [the official AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) and `s3.upload()` seems to be a thing. I have no idea why I get an error.

If I `console.log(s3.upload)` I get `undefined`.

Node.js v13.11.0.

**EDIT**

I ended up using `s3.putObject()` which does pretty much the same thing as `s3.upload()`, and works, while the latter is still inexplicably undefined...

```
console.log(`typeof s3.upload = `);
console.log(typeof s3.upload); // undefined?? WHY

console.log(`typeof s3.putObject = `);
console.log(typeof s3.putObject); // function, and works
```

Comment: what about other methods ? is it only specific to `upload` ?

Comment: `console.log(s3.copyObject)` gives `[ 'length', 'name', 'arguments', 'caller', 'prototype' ]` so it is defined. Same thing for `console.log(s3.createBucket)`, it's not undefined. Looks like the problem is specific to `upload` indeed

Comment: Thanks for the update about putObject, really helped me.

Comment: putObject may not work for every case. Ex https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2961

Answer (score 2):

Use putObject, example:

```
s3.client.putObject({
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: 'folder/file.txt',
      Body: data,
      ACL: 'public-read'
   }, function (res) {
      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.');
})
```

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

Can also try reinstalling aws-sdk package.
Refer: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/916#issuecomment-191012462

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but the problem remains. `s3.upload` is still undefined (although other methods like `s3.createBucket` are not)

Comment: considering you are able to perform other s3 related operations successfully like listBucket,createBucket,listObjects.